# Capture network interface device name with Packetbeat

Tags: networking, logs, network-interface, elasticsearch

With Packetbeat on Linux, the `packetbeat.interfaces.device: any` configuration captures all messages sent or received by the server where Packetbeat is installed.

I want to distinguish the messages captured by the interface over which they were exchanged e.g. which messages were exchanged over interface `eth0` and which ones were exchanged over `wlan0`. From the logs, I couldn't find a field with this information.

Is there a way to include the interface device name with Packetbeat logs using some configuration? If not, are there any alternative ways that I could go about capturing the same with the Packetbeat logs?

Answer (score 0):

Packetbeat seems to be more application- or transaction-focused than a classic network analyzer: essentially, it's a network analyzer for application developers, and focuses on Layer-3 and above.

If the IP addresses are not enough to specify the interface, then you are doing bridging or some more advanced Layer-2 manipulations. If you need Layer-2 information (= physical interfaces, MAC addresses, Ethernet frame headers), then Packetbeat seems to be the wrong tool; for low-level details like that, you would need a network analyzer designed for network engineers instead.

It could be argued that the need to figure out whether particular traffic came from `eth0` or `wlan0` could suggest a possible network design issue: if the IP addresses cannot successfully identify them, then you might be bridging together two network segments with different security postures (bad idea!) or perhaps your hosts and/or routers don't have adequate *reverse path filtering* (so you should perhaps fix that first).